# Decoding url in Angular.js services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code for my service:

```
appServices.factory("Article", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://content.guardianapis.com/:articleId?api-key=7z8bnh6z57zjyx6qef2ujz4w", {}, {
        query: {method:"GET", params:{articleId:"people"}, isArray:true}
    });
});
```

It should be working fine, but the Guardian API doesn't work with encoded urls. I need to decode the :articleId only, since the other part is already decoded.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please check ajax request angular making through *$resource*, in developers tools.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is what I get, but it works fine when I remove the dynamic :articleId which is served encoded from Angular.js, and directly input a static decoded url into the code.

Comment: Show us the sample code you are using to retrieve the Articles.

Comment: @AmarSyla yes. 404 is response. check what request being sent i.e. Request Url, Request Payload in chrome developer tools or firefox firebug.